# FIRStorageMetadata get timeCreation

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I retrieve timeCreation `FIRStorageMetadata` of a file located in firebase storage?

Comment: I'd suggest that you check out the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, straight from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata):

```
// Create reference to the file whose metadata we want to retrieve
FIRStorageReference *forestRef = [storageRef child:@"images/forest.jpg"];

 // Get metadata properties
[forestRef metadataWithCompletion:^(FIRStorageMetadata *metadata, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    } else {
        // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
    }
}];
```

And if you inspect the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/c33bdff405b988ffa4e894809db73ade0f21e658/Firebase/Storage/Public/FIRStorageMetadata.h) - namely the class you're referring to, `FIRStorageMetadata`, you'll find that one field:

`@property(copy, nonatomic, readonly, nullable) NSDate *timeCreated;`